# Select option cannot submit in the database using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiuQb.jpg)

> Model lesson_model.php

```
function fetch_data() {   
  $course_code = $this->session->userdata('course_code'); 
  $this->db->select('*');  
  $this->db->from('chapter');
  $this->db->order_by('chapter.chapter_number', 'ASC');
  $this->db->where('course_code', $course_code);
  $query = $this->db->get();  
  return $query;  
}
```

> Controller Add_Lesson.php

```
function __construct() { 
  parent::__construct(); 
  $this->load->helper('url');
  $this->load->model('lesson_model');
  $this->load->database(); 
} 

public function index() {
  $data["fetch_data"] = $this->lesson_model->fetch_data();
  $this->load->view("lesson/add", $data);
}
```

> View add.php

```
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-12">Chapter Number</label>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <select type="text" id="chapter_number" name="chapter_number" class="form-control form-control-line">
            <option disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
            <?php foreach($option->result() as $row) {        
            echo '<option value="'.$row->chapter_title.'">'.$row->chapter_number.'</option>';   
            } 
            ?> 
          </select>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("chapter_number"); ?></span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-9 form-group">  
        <label class="col-md-12">Chapter Title</label>
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="text" id="title" name="chapter_title" class="form-control"/>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("chapter_title"); ?></span>
          </div>
      </div>

      <script>
        $('#chapter_number').on('change', function() {
            var selected = $( "#chapter_number" ).val();
            $('input[name="chapter_title"]').val(selected);
        });
      </script>
    </div
```

> The only problem is when I submit only the chapter title will appear correctly in database and the chapter number is 0 even if I set the chapter number to 1.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong values in first select. you should use chapter number instead of title  because number is an integer it won't take string variable  as you are doing with chapter title. Update your code

```
 <div class="col-md-2 form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-12">Chapter Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <select type="text" id="chapter_number" name="chapter_number" class="form-control form-control-line">
        <option disabled="" selected="">Select</option>
        <?php foreach($option->result() as $row) {        
        echo '<option value="'.$row->chapter_number.'">'.$row->chapter_number.'</option>';   
        } 
        ?> 
      </select>
      <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error("chapter_number"); ?></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: oh okay.. did you see my screenshot? I would like to be like that and insert in database.. can you teach me how?

Comment: first you need to insert the values and then display them as you want.

Comment: I would like that.. if I select the chapter number it automatically appear the title in the input field.

Comment: you need to use jquery for that. On select send chapter number to data base and fetch the corresponding record and display that in the text area. search for tutotrial on that

Comment: I already have the script but the chapter number is always zero..

Comment: your code needs a lot of modifications. Please read tutorials for that.

Comment: could you please mark this as answer if it solve this your issue

Comment: the result is not appropriate with my needs.. when I select chapter as 1 the input field print 1 also..